# ER to Relational Schema?

Tags: database-design, uml, erd, tool-uml

I have developed an ERD diagram with UML notation in StarUML.

I need to draw a relational schema but due to lack of features in StarUML I must use another tool.

What exactly goes into a relational schema?

And can someone recommend me a good tool?

Visio? But I would have to redraw the whole thing again.

Seems like starUML allows me to export XMI 1.1 for UML 1.3 and XMI 1.1 for UML 1.3 Rose Extended. I don't understand what these mean or their purpose, perhaps I can import the XMI into other tool?

Here is my ERD.

[image: Entity relationship diagram]

The following is what I am being asked to do next:

> A relational schema of your database in 3NF, clearly  indicating
> attributes, the data type of each attribute,  primary and foreign keys
> and which attributes are  nullable, giving reasons.  List any
> assumptions you need  to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well..as you have to define the attributes for all your entities, you have to define your entities again. Your relational schema should contain the attributes of each entity, the primary and foreign key relationships, good-to-have features are constraints(if you want to define them as well).
The tools that I use quite frequently:
 - Enterprise Architect(EA) - A good tool that can even do reverse engineering for you.
 - Gliffy - A lightweight online tool for creating diagrams.

Apart from these, there are plenty of tool available on the net.

Comment: Should i just create the database setting all the contrains, primary and foreign keys manually and then have visio or EA reverse engineer it from sql or oracle?? ive never done this what do you recommend

Comment: You have to create the attribute, primary/foreign keys manually. After creating the ER diagram, it all depends on your requirement that what you wanna do, do you want to create a schema script/db from your diagram? If yes, then you can do that using EA.